# Wordpress: Different redirects for each distinct donation amount?

Tags: paypal, wordpress, response.redirect

In my wordpress site, I need a paypal donation feature to work so, if, for example, they donate $5+, they are taken to one page(redirect). If they donate $7+, they are taken to another, and so on. I've tried multiple donation plugins, but all of them only have one URL you can use after a donation.

Any plugin you know of or other way this can be done would be appreciated.

Comment: well you could write something clever with javascript or php probably.  The paypal API isn't terribly complicated. Also, FYI, wordpress.stackexchange.com *might* be a bit better place to ask something like this. Or even reddit.com/r/wordpress for plugin reccomendations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either write your own plugin or an extension of one of the ones you've already tried.

Basically, you'll set the redirect URL in your payment code (whether API or standard HTML checkout) to a page that will use PHP or whatever you're comfortable with to check the amount and then do another redirect based on that.  Nobody would ever seen that page, of course.  They would just see their final page based on their donation amount.

Again, though, if you can't find an existing plugin that gives you that option you can easily customize it.  That's the beauty of WordPress and (properly developed) plugins!